# Does QThread::quit() discard all events in EventQueue?

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

There is `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    Worker w;
    QObject::connect(&w, SIGNAL(done()), &a, SLOT(quit()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    w.start();

    int ret = a.exec();
    w.quit();
    w.wait();

    return ret;
}
```

And there is `Worker`'s definition:

```
class Worker : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Worker(QObject *parent=0);
protected:
    void run();
protected slots:
    void process_request();
private:
    int ttl;
    Messenger* messenger;
}

Worker::Worker(QObject * parent)
    :QThread(parent),
    ttl(5),
    messenger(new Messenger(this))
{
    moveToThread(this);
    connect(messenger, SIGNAL(new_message()), SLOT(process_request()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void Worker::finish(){
  quit();
  messenger->disconnectFromNetwork();   
}

void Worker::run(){
  messenger->connectToNetwork("somewhere");
  exec();
  emit done();
}

void Worker::process_request(){
    net_message msg;
    messenger->recv(msg);

    // PROCESSING

    messenger->send(msg);

    BOOST_LOG_SEV(file_log, severity::notification) << "TTL = " << ttl;
    if (--ttl == 0) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Well, sorry for the long exposition. The idea was that the Messenger lives in the main thread, and pokes the Worker when it has a new message for it, and the Worker lives only a certain amount of messages, after which it stops and shuts down entire application.

But there is a problem: the log file has lines `TTL = -1`, and `TTL = -2`, and such. It shouldn't, and the only reason I can think about is that `quit()` doesn't quite ends the event loop: it allows pending events to be processed before returning from `exec()`. Is it so? If "no", then what may cause such a behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all ["You're doing that wrong"](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Secondly documentation doesn't say what is the state of queue in event loop after exit was called. It is possible that `exec()` returns after event queue is empty to make sure that all asynchronous cleanups are done (in case if this it top most event loop, in this case it is).

---

edit:
I've [checked source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qeventloop.cpp.html). Apparently [`QEventLoop::processEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html#processEvents) is call between each check that event loop should exit. So it looks like `exec()` returns only when queue is empty.

Comment: I know it is not the most correct way. And now that you confirm that pending events are processed between `quit()` call and actual returning from `exec()`, I guess I have to refactor quite a lot of legacy code. What a joy. Anyway, could you please sketch up the correct way of doing this thing?

Comment: Very well, I split my class in two parts, but I still need to put `if (ttl <= 0) return;` in the beginning of the `process_request()`. Then what's the big difference, especially since I don't want an "object for manipulating a thread" plus "a task for executing", I just want one "object representing a task in a separate thread".